# Several method test issue - hang on second test- Robotium with ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, unit-testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, robotium

**What I'm doing:** I'm testing an Android aplication using Robotium.

**What works:** If I have a test in one test method everithing works fine

**What doesn't work:** If I try do divide this test in to two smaller, then the first test is passing, and the second is hanging (or freezing - I don't know how to name that)
[image]

**Why I need that** I need that to make reports in sppon showing bars for each test (I will have: testLogin, testAddCustomer, testLogout etc). Example of spoon report looks like this:

[image]

If i have one big test (testAll) there is only one big green bar, but I need to have many short bars for each test method like on the image above.

**What I've done:** I have read a lot of different topics about simillar problems but it didn't help me

Here is an short example of what works (one method - *testAll()*) I wrote currents activities in comments:

```
public class LogInLogOut extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {
    private Solo solo;
    private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME = "mobile.touch.core.activity.SplashScreenActivity";
    private static Class<?> launcherActivityClass;
    static {
        try {
            launcherActivityClass = Class.forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public LogInLogOut() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        super(launcherActivityClass);
    }

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation());
        getActivity();
    }
    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        try {
            solo.finalize();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getActivity().finish();
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public void testAll() {
        // here is LoginActivity <<-----
        // username
        solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(0x3));
        solo.enterText((android.widget.EditText) solo.getView(0x3), "user");
        // enter password
        solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(0x3, 1));
        solo.enterText((android.widget.EditText) solo.getView(0x3, 1), "password");
        // click on log in button
        solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(android.widget.Button.class, 0));

        // here ContainerActivity starts <<-----
        //click on log out
        solo.clickOnMenuItem("LogOut");
       }
}
```

With the *testAll ()* method all test is passed. But I need to divide that into *testLogin()* and test *testLogout()*.

here is how I divide metod testAll into two smaller (*testLogin()* & *testLogout()*):

```
public void testLogin() {
    // here is LoginActivity <<-----
    // username
    solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(0x3));
    solo.enterText((android.widget.EditText) solo.getView(0x3), "user");
    // enter password
    solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(0x3, 1));
    solo.enterText((android.widget.EditText) solo.getView(0x3, 1), "password");
    // click on log in button
    solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(android.widget.Button.class, 0));
    // here ContainerActivity starts <<-----
}
public void testOut() {
    //click on log out
    solo.clickOnMenuItem("LogOut");
   }
```

Now first test (*testLogin()*) is passed and the second (*testLogout()*) is hanging

To check if the test even started I put log into it.

```
public void testOut() {
    Log.i("checkTestB", "test B started"); <<-- here is the log
    //click on log out
    solo.clickOnMenuItem("LogOut");
   }
```

It occurse that the testLog is not ececuting the code, becouse "test B started" was not in the log

**Question:** How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find answer. Method setUp() is perormed before **each** test method, and tearDown() is performed after **each** test method. It coused the problem.

I override setUp() and tearDown() with:

```
@Override
    public void setUp() {

    }
@Override
protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    if (exit == true) {
        try {
            solo.finalize();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

Then I wrote my own mehtods startUp() identical like setUp() and tearDown() deleted.

```
public void startUp() {
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation());
        getActivity();
    }
```

Then setUp() do nothig when it is performed before test. The same thing is with teadDown() it makes nothing unltil I will set exit==true in test method.

**The resolution is to start manulay startUp() in FIRST test method and in the LAST test method exit=ture (default is false), then tearDown() will run and close everything.**

Now I manually start activity in testLogin():

```
public void testLogin() {
    startUp(); <<<<<<<-----------------same method as setUp() but can started manually
    solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(0x3));
    solo.enterText((android.widget.EditText) solo.getView(0x3), "user");
    solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(0x3, 1));
    solo.enterText((android.widget.EditText) solo.getView(0x3, 1), "password");
    solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(android.widget.Button.class, 0));
}
```

In the second methods testLogout() I use on the begginig: solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation()); and turnDown() method on the end

```
public void testLogOut() {
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation());
    solo.clickOnMenuItem("LogOut");
   exit=true;
    }
```